# How to version a REST API using URL versioning scheme using Azure API Management and Azure Functions without duplicating v2/v2 in route

Tags: azure, rest, azure-functions, versioning, azure-api-management

We have 3 end goals

- Add API Versioning via url schema (e.g v1/resource, v2/resource)
- Have a swagger UI that developers can explore our REST API
- Automate everything with CI/CD

We have a REST API that uses an API Management Service and an Azure Function.
Our DevOps flow is to export the OpenAPI Spec doc using the [azure functions openapi extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension). Then import the OpenAPI Spec into the API Management Service as a new API Version via terraform.
The problem is we must have a unique route specified in our azure function Attribute
`[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "v1/creative-fields")]`
`[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "v2/creative-fields")]`

Then when we specify a version set in Azure API Management service, it asks for a versioning strategy (which we specify as url based versioning and give it version path "baseurl/v1" for v1 and "baseurl/v2" for v2

Now when we invite users to our Developer portal or view it in the API Management service in azure portal, the url shows as `baseurl/v2/v2/creative-fields`

We have explored a few options, but none seem to solve all our problems

- Don't utilize API Management service versioning - but then in the APIM Swagger Dev Portal all the endpoints show up in one list (not broken down by API Version)
- Use a completely different CI/CD flow for generating our openapi spec doc/swagger ui